# finish button is not enabling in eclipse after installing java ee tools in eclipse juno

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I am trying in install Eclipse java ee developer tools in eclipse. When I click "accept the license" finish button is not enabled. [image]

can anyone suggest me how to resolve this. Thanks in advance for your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether Eclipse java ee developer tools already installed or not.If it is installed then remove it and try to install it again